# How do You get a third script to handle information of two other scripts related to GUIs in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, signals, qprocess

I have recreated a problem I am encountering as a minimal example below.

The situation: I have two Qt Designer generated GUI, each being called by their own separated scripts. A third script is meant to collect information from the first script upon the click of a button on the second script. I does not, yet there is no errors.

I have also attempted to solve this by using signals, but these does not seem to communicate between scripts. I provided a simpler version here that doesn't use signals per se.

My question is: How do You get a third script to handle information of two other scripts related to GUIs in pyqt5 ?

Here is the minimal example:

The first GUI script:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(504, 223)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.TypeHere = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.TypeHere.setObjectName("TypeHere")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.TypeHere)
        self.HelloButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.HelloButton.setObjectName("HelloButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.HelloButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 504, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.HelloButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Say hello"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The second GUI script:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(282, 392)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton01 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton01.setObjectName("pushButton01")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton01)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 282, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton01.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

JustSomeTextv01, the script of the first GUI:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess, QThreadPool
from TypingUIv01 import Ui_MainWindow
import JustSomeButtonsv01 as JSB
import sys

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.HelloButton.pressed.connect(self.openButtons)
        self.Display = JSB.Window()
        self.ButtonsThread()
        
    def openButtons(self):
        self.Display.show()
    def ButtonsThread(self):
        self.threadpoolbutt = QThreadPool()
        self.threadpoolbutt.start(self.runButtons)
    def runButtons(self):
        self.butt = QProcess()
        print("Buttons Running")
        self.butt.execute('python',['JustSomeButtonsv01.py'])
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

JustSomeButtonsv01, the script of the second GUI:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess, QThreadPool
from ButtonsUIv01 import Ui_MainWindow
# import JustSomeRecordv01 as JSR
import sys

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.RecordThread()
    
    def RecordThread(self):
        self.threadpoolrec = QThreadPool()
        self.threadpoolrec.start(self.runRecord)
    def runRecord(self):
        self.rec = QProcess()
        print("Record Running")
        self.rec.execute('python',['JustSomeRecordv01.py'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    # window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

And finally, JustSomeRecordv01, the third script trying to interact with the other two:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys
from TypingUIv01 import Ui_MainWindow as JSTWin
from ButtonsUIv01 import Ui_MainWindow as ButtWin

class Record(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # self.setupUi(self)
        app2 = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.Win = JSTWin()
        self.Win.setupUi(MainWindow)
        self.Text = self.Win.TypeHere.toPlainText()
        print("Running")
        self.Butt = ButtWin()
        self.Butt.setupUi(MainWindow)
        self.Butt.pushButton01.pressed.connect(self.PrintIT)
    def PrintIT(self):
        print("Texting")
        print(self.Text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Record()
    # window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

How to reproduce the problem:
You execute the JustSomeTextv01 script. Press the "Hello Button" and a second window will show up. You type anything in the QTextEdit of the first window and then click the button of the second window. The intent is that this second button would print what You wrote, but it doesn't work.

Thank You for your time,

Comment: You could use sockets targeting the localhost address. It's a way to do [IPC](https://eng.libretexts.org/Courses/Delta_College/Operating_System%3A_The_Basics/05%3A_Process_Synchronization/5.4%3A_Interprocess_Communication), which is probably what you're after here.

Comment: What is the actual use case for this behaviour?

Comment: @AdEp Alexander correctly points out an important aspect: there are rare case for which one really needs to run a separate process for a python script *from* a python script, especially if they are part of the same project/codebase. I'm under the impression that you're having a [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): looking for the wrong answer for the wrong question. Please explain what you are actually trying to do, because you probably just need to use threading or plain simple **better code**.

Comment: Perhaps!
This is all part of a more complex project of course, but in a nutshell:
I'm trying to save the entry information from the first and second window when a button is pressed on a second window. Both of these windows have a bunch of options and other commands so I have a separate script to handle each.
Thus, I'm writing everything "save" related in a third script since I'm trying to save information from several window on the same trigger (pressing the button).

Comment: @AdEp why do you have to force your users to use 3 applications at the same time to do one thing? Why not using 1 application, and if you need more windows, just open a new `QDialog`?

Comment: @CarlHR I figured I needed to since each window is filled with forms to fill and buttons to control devices, etc. All needing to run in parallel of course. If I put everything within a single script I would end up with 10,000 lines in no time. I prefer having several smaller digestible parts that communicates with each other.

Comment: @AdEp then my first suggestion remains. It's won't be easy at first to implement a socket-based communication between processes, as it still requires some knowledge on the area + multithreading (if you don't want to freeze the GUIs). But *it can solve your problem* if done right.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it within the example scripts, but the only solution was to put everything not-GUI into the same script as so:

```
# To test textbox related function
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from TypingUIv01 import Ui_MainWindow
from ButtonsUIv01 import Ui_MainWindow as Ui2
import sys

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    PatchSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.HelloButton.pressed.connect(self.openButtons)
        self.PatchSignal.connect(self.printIT)
        
    def openButtons(self):
        self.w2 = Wintwo()
        self.w2.show()
    
    def printIT(self):
        self.Text = self.TypeHere.toPlainText()
        # print("PRINTING")
        print(self.Text)

class Wintwo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton01.pressed.connect(self.Emit)
        self.emitter = window
    def Emit(self):
        # print("EMITTING")
        self.emitter.PatchSignal.emit()

        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

It seems sending Signals between scripts is simply not possible in pyqt5!

Somehow this doesn't work in my actual script since "window" isn't recognized, but that's another question for another day.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).